# Is it good to extend lambdas in kotlin

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I'm relatively new in kotlin programming, and recently I found out that this is a valid statement:

```
class Test : (Int) -> String {
    override fun invoke(p1: Int): String {
        return p1.toString()
    }
}
```

When I see it I have a feeling that it might be not very good programming practice to extend Lambdas, however I don't have any objective reasons to think so. I haven't found any docs regarding the issue, so could you please advise if it is good or bad to extend lambdas.

Comment: I think it's reasonable if you can limit that extension to a specific "context" and you need to decorate each lambda for some side effect or something... But i'm also interested in other responses.

Comment: This comment seems to be about defining extension functions on function types, while the question is about subclassing them. As for the latter, it's rather odd, but if you need it, I don't see why you shouldn't.

Comment: Just wondering what the specific use case is. `fun test(p: Int) = p.toString()` seems easier to write :)

Comment: I think there are real-life use cases. For example, one might want to have implementations of function types that store some state between the calls. While it can be easily done with closures, using a class feels more like proper OOP. Additionally, using a custom class allows you to define additional API in the same type or even implement multiple function types at once.

Comment: The library I use has API that requires a lambda as `map()` method parameter. I have multiple implementations of `Transformer` object, that extends lambda, so I can use them in different places of the app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function types like `(Int) -> String` are technically interfaces (as described in this [detailed spec doc](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/spec-docs/function-types.md)), so if you feel the need to implement them in your classes, there's nothing to stop you from doing so.

If you do so, you'll be able to use instances of your class where `(Int) -> String` and `Int.() -> String` functions are expected.

If you only need to invoke instances of your class with the function syntax but not to use them as instances of function types, it is enough to just define the [`invoke(...)` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#invoke) as a member or an extension function.

---

UPD: In Kotlin 1.4 another way to clearly describe the semantics of API that receives a function is [functional interfaces](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/fun-interfaces.html). Using them, you define an interface marked as `fun`, and the caller may either pass a lambda or implement your interface directly. Before Kotlin 1.4, such a conversion on the call site was only available for Java interfaces.